# reactjs if statement in state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react and I trying to setup state base on if else statement. So far I came up with this code:

```
this.state {
  min:(if(parseInt(this.props.min) <=1){return 1})
}
```

is that legal to do in state? if not what can I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.state = { min: parseInt(this.props.min, 10) <= 1 && 1 }`

This will return you either `1` or `false`;

Preferably to have the same type of data, so better to add a fallback:

`this.state = { min: parseInt(this.props.min, 10) <= 1 ? 1 : 0 }`

If you want to do more than one `if`, I'd suggest you to separate it into a function, something like:

```
function getMin() {
  const value = parseInt(this.props.min, 10);
  if (!value || isNaN(value)) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (value <= 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  else if (...) {
    return ...;
  }
  return 0;
}

this.state = {
  min: getMin()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I want to do more than one if statment? let's say if and else if statments, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using a nested shortcut `if` with `?` (of course, you can do it). It'd be better to separate it into a function - I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this if you want. I assumed 0 would be another value you wanted.
Trade with with whatever you want.

```
this.state = {
  min: parseInt(this.props.min) <= 1 ? 1 : 0,
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I want to do more than one if statment? let's say if and else if statments, how can I accomplish that?